# Continuous function with irrational period - summation over naturals converges to 0?

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

A friend gave me this problem as a "Christmas gift":

> If $f$ is periodic with irrational period $r$ and $\int_0^r f(x) \mathrm{d}x = 0$, prove or disprove that $\left\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n f(i)\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded.

One construction that works is $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{if } x \equiv k \pmod{r}, k \in \mathbb{Z} \\
0 & \mbox{otherwise } \end{cases}$ (I guess this only works if we use the Lebesgue integral); another is $f(x) = \tan(x-\frac{\pi}{2})$.

However, he accidentally forgot to specify that $f$ must be continuous, which invalidates both of these constructions. Since $\mathbb{N} \pmod{r}$ is uniformly distributed in $[0, r)$, I'm pretty sure that we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(i) = \int_{0}^{r}f(x)\mathrm{d}x = 0.$$ Unfortunately, this is weaker than the original statement.

My question is, is the original statement true, and if not, what's a counterexample? I'm not sure if this problem can be solved with elementary knowledge, or if it would require some more theory.

Comment: you might consider adding dynamics or ergodic theory tags

Comment: (since you are basically asking about the rate of convergence of ergodic averages under an irrational rotation of $S^1$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this is not true for continuous functions.
Take $r = 2\pi$. Continuous functions with vanishing integral form Banach space.
Define linear operators from this space: $$T_n (f) = f(1) + f(2) + \dots +f(n)$$
If the claim were true then (by Banach-Steinhaus, a.k.a. uniform boundedenss principle)
$||T_n|| \lt C$ where $C$ is a constant independent from $n$.
In particular, taking for $f_k(t) = \exp(ikt)$ we would get (for any $k \neq 0$)
$$|\exp(ik \cdot 1) + \exp(ik \cdot 2) + \dots + \exp(ik \cdot n)| \lt C$$
But the sum on the left is:
$$\frac{|\exp(ik\cdot n) - 1|}{|\exp(ik) - 1|}$$ and this should be bounded by a constant independent of $k$ and $n$.
Here is where irrationality of $r$ comes into play (that is uniform distribution of $r\cdot k$ and
$r\cdot n\cdot k$).
First take $k$ so that denominator is small and then ($k$ is now fixed and $r\cdot k$ is irrational) take $n$ so that nominator is not small.

Comment: Very nice!  Well done!